# How do i remove "Powered by WordPress" from AMP?

Tags: plugins, xampp

how do I remove "Powered By Wordpress" from the AMP version of my website? It would be great if you suggest a CSS or Plugin for this. I use the basic AMP plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To remove “Powered by WordPress,” from the AMP plugin’s footer.php template file.
>    [Reference](https://www.wordpress-web-design.co/remove-powered-wordpress-amp-plugin.html)

**This new file should reside at:**

```
wp-content/themes/yourtheme/amp/footer.php
```

**Footer.php**

```
<footer class="amp-wp-footer">
    <div>
        <h2><?php echo esc_html( $this->get( 'blog_name' ) ); ?></h2>
        <a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><?php _e( 'Back to top', 'amp' ); ?></a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

This will ensure that Remove Powered WordPress AMP Plugin will still remain after the plugin is updated next time.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @FahadUrRehmanKhan code updated. Hope this code may be work for you.

Comment: I couldn't find the amp folder in my theme. I use the basic AMP plugin.

Comment: @FahadUrRehmanKhan you should create "amp" folder under the theme and create "footer.php" file and copy the above code which i mentioned in my answer and save it and test it.

Comment: @FahadUrRehmanKhan Welcome.